# Does new tab segration require usercontext ui in firefox?

Tags: firefox, containers

Does the `privacy.usercontext.about_newtab_segregation.enabled` setting require `privacy.userContext.enabled` to be true?

The second setting enabled the required menu items for container tabs (even when `privacy.userContext.ui.enabled` is disabled), which is no default at the moment (firefox 52).